# How can I depend on a Java project inside sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a sbt project and I want to include a Java project as a dependency in my sbt project. The Java project has a maven pom.xml and its on github. Its located here: https://github.com/ggrandes/bouncer

How to use a java project as a dependency within sbt?

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/using-github-projects-scala-library-dependencies-sbt-sbteclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only depend on other SBT projects from Git repositories, AFAIK. But the README says "Current Stable Version is 2.2.7" with "2.2.7" hyperlinked to https://maven-release.s3.amazonaws.com/release/org/javastack/bouncer/2.2.7/bouncer-2.2.7-bin.zip.

So

```
resolvers += "AWS Maven Repo" at "https://maven-release.s3.amazonaws.com/release/"

libraryDependencies += "org.javastack" % "bouncer" % "2.2.7"
```

should probably do the trick. Alternately (e.g. if you want to use GitHub `master` version), clone the project and publish it to your local repository.